# Deploy SAPUI5 application to ABAP repository

Tags: sapui5, manifest.json, component.js

I started developping an UI5 application in SAP Web IDE. At this moment, I just run it in a test Fiori Launchpad. The next step will be to deploy it to our ABAP repository. I guess I need to adapt some parts of the application for this reason (or add some file). This is my actual project structure:

[image: project structure]

When I want to make it run on the ABAP AS...

- Are there important files missing?
- How should the manifest.json and Component.js be adapted? (e.g. paths)
- Have you got some more hints?

Answer (score 1):

if the application runs in the web ide, the application usually will run deployed to a server on this server as well. i.e.:

1. if the application runs in the web ide, there are no files missing.
2. if the application runs in the web ide, the `Manifest.json` and `Component.json` do not need to be adapted.
3. just test the application deployed: deploy the application through the web ide or go to transaction `SE38` and run the program `/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD`. after deploying the application the same should be seeable in transaction `SE80` within `bsp applications`. Then set up the application for the fiori launchpad: transaction `LPD_CUST`. After that set up the application in the fiori launchpad designer: transaction `/UI2/FLPD_CUST`. Thereafter create a role in transaction `PFCG` for the in the FLPD created group which contains the tile connected to the corresponding application. Now the tile for the application should be addable within the fiori launchpad.

Comment: Thank you. My application uses Cordova plugin (using Hybrid Application Toolkit from the Cloud Platform). Do you know if the HAT is supported within the server? Has it to be installed?

Comment: to which kind of server do you refer? a hybrid application is not a web application. therefore it's not possible to run a hybrid application in the fiori launchpad.

Comment: I make use of [sap.ndc.BarcodeScanner](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ndc.BarcodeScanner). I would like to [include my UI5 app to our Hybris Marketing system](https://help.sap.com/viewer/307cdb0f1a69422bb23b9ee426bd39f7/1802%20YMKT/en-US/41f3a1b4cd484efc9ba2cc49184a430f.html) (running on NetWeaver Application Server ABAP). Since my app is hybrid, it does not work in browser but refering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40715814/deploying-barcode-scanner-app-to-abap-repository) and Michael Jess answer it should be accessible with SAP Fiori Client or not? Regards.